# Add string to beginning of another string

Tags: ios, string, swift

**Basic question**

I have 2 strings. I want to add one string to another? Here's an example:

```
var secondString= "is your name."
var firstString = "Mike, "
```

Here I have 2 strings. I want to add `firstString` to `secondString`, NOT vice versa. (Which would be: `firstString += secondString`.)

**More detail**

I have 5 `string`

```
let first = "7898"
let second = "00"
let third = "5481"
let fourth = "4782"

var fullString = "\(third):\(fourth)"
```

I know for sure that `third` and `fourth` will be in `fullString`, but I don't know about `first` and `second`.

So I will make an `if statement` checking if `second` has `00`. If it does, `first` and `second` won't go in `fullString`. If it doesn't, `second will go into`fullString`.

Then I will check if `first` has `00`. If it does, then `first` won't go inside of `fullString`, and if not, it will go.

The thing is, I need them in the same order: first, second, third fourth. So in the if statement, I need a way to potentially add `first` and `second` at the beginning of `fullString`.

Comment: ... did you try secondString += firstString ?

Comment: I update the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Re. your basic question:

```
 secondString = "\(firstString)\(secondString)"
```

or

```
secondString = firstString + secondString
```

Here is a way to insert string at the beginning "without resetting" per your comment (`first` at front of `second`):

```
let range = second.startIndex..<second.startIndex
second.replaceRange(range, with: first)
```

Re. your "more detail" question:

```
var fullString: String

if second == "00" {
    fullString = third + fourth
} else if first == "00" {
    fullString = second + third + fourth
} else {
    fullString = first + second + third + fourth
}
```

Comment: I can do that, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without resetting the string.

Comment: See my latest comment.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with 4 if statements, and still couldn't get it right!

Answer (score 4):

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID291):

> String values can be added together (or concatenated) with the addition operator (+) to create a new String value:

```
let string1 = "hello"
let string2 = " there"
var welcome = string1 + string2
// welcome now equals "hello there"
```

> You can also append a String value to an existing String variable with the addition assignment operator (+=):

```
var instruction = "look over"
instruction += string2
// instruction now equals "look over there"
```

> You can append a Character value to a String variable with the String type’s append() method:

```
let exclamationMark: Character = "!"
welcome.append(exclamationMark)
// welcome now equals "hello there!"
```

So you are pretty much free to add these in any way shape or form.
 Which includes

```
secondstring += firststring
```

Edit to accommodate the new information:
[Strings in Swift are mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221786/are-swift-mutable-strings-really-mutable-or-are-they-just-like-java-strings) which means you can always add to a string in-place without recreating any objects.

Something like (pseudo-code)

```
if(second != "00")
{
  fullstring = second + fullstring
  //only do something with first if second != 00
  if(first != "00")
  {
   fullstring = first + fullstring
  }
}
```